# Problems with routing in Angular

Tags: angular, routes

I am going to ask a question that I have seen many times and I have searched a lot about it, it seems that everyone has the same problem, but nobody is solved the same.

I'm doing a hello world with Angular and I'm on the routing side. I have generated the file as it says the docs of the framework, but when I start opening the application in the navigator it jumps to the following error:

```
 Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RouterOutlet -> ChildrenOutletContexts]: 
 StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterOutlet -> ChildrenOutletContexts]: 
 NullInjectorError: No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts!
```

I have followed the tutorial since the beginning several times, I have looked for solutions and nothing. To see if someone can help me, I show you my code, just as it is right now:

This is the app-routing.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HelloWorldComponent } from './hello-world/hello- 
world.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HelloWorldComponent,
  },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

this is the app.modules file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { MatButtonModule, MatDialogModule, MatTableModule,MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserCardComponent, DialogExampleComponent} from './usercard/user-card.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platformbrowser/animations';
import { HelloWorldComponent } from './hello-world/helloworld.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  UserCardComponent,
  DialogExampleComponent,
  HelloWorldComponent
],
entryComponents:[DialogExampleComponent],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
MatTableModule,
MatButtonModule,
MatDialogModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
MatFormFieldModule,
MatInputModule,
FormsModule,
RouterModule,
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And I do not think it's necessary, but this is the app.component.html file:

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Can anyone see the problem?? Maybe I'm blind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've already set up routing in your `AppRoutingModule` and you've also exported the `RouterModule` the `AppRoutingModule`, that's what you should be adding to the `imports` array of your `AppModule`.

Change this:

```
imports: [
  ...
  RouterModule,
],
```

To this:

```
imports: [
  ...
  AppRoutingModule,
],
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-basic-eg-for-stack-overflow?file=src/app/app.module.ts) for your ref.